# What can affect a player's speed in Halo 3 multiplayer?

Tags: halo-3

Why is it sometimes in Halo 3 multiplayer one character will move slower than the others or two characters will move slower than a third. What things affect speed? Does damage slow you down?

Comment: It has been so long. I can't quite remember.  But I suspect that it is lag. I suspect that it's only what you are seeing. And that the actual movement speed doesn't change.

Answer (score 3):

You might be a little more specific as to when exactly you see this speed discrepancy amongst players, but off the top of my head:

- Crouching
- Sprinting
- It's been a while, but I think Power Drain or one of the other consumables has some effect on speed while the players stand in it or walk through it
- Sword lunging
- Being hit by another fast-moving object (i.e. a vehicle)
- Being hit by a concussive force, like a gravity hammer or grenade blast
- Mancannons/grav lifts
- Lag

Answer (score 2):

It is lag if you are playing online, if you are playing custom games on a forge map however, There may be a custom powerup that increases speed or the leader may be set to be slower on the game mode.  I believe that is all that can affect speed of one player but not another in Halo 3.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to other answers: Walking forwards is faster than strafing sideways or backwards.